# Removing a part of the string starting and ending with regular expression in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a set of strings starting with [ANONYMOUS], and ending with ; sign.
I'd like to remove this part from the set of strings.

For example, I have this string:

```
"[ANONYMOUS],1756 , An Intro, V19;BIAN C, 2016, WINIT, V7, P83;"
```

and I'd like to have this:

```
"BIAN C, 2016, WINIT, V7, P83;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `sub` to match the pattern `[` (it is a metacharacter so we escape `\\`), from the start (`^`) of the string followed by the string 'ANONYMOUS', then the closing bracket `]` and one or more characters that are not a `;` (`[^;]+`), and replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("^\\[ANONYMOUS\\][^;]+;", "", str1)
```

#### data

```
str1 <- '[ANONYMOUS],1756 , An Intro, V19;BIAN C, 2016, WINIT, V7, P83;'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_extract` and lookbehind and lookahead:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "(?<=;).*(?=;)")
[1] "BIAN C, 2016, WINIT, V7, P83"
```

This pattern matches anything (`.*`) between a semicolon to the left (`(?<=;)`)--the lookbehind--and a semicolon to the right (`(?=;)`)--the lookahead.